# How do I get the result I want ? SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Have a problem with my SQL Server stored procedure query output. Currently using this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Head H
INNER JOIN Line L ON H.invno = L.invno
INNER JOIN Misc M ON H.invno = M.invno
INNER JOIN QSMU Q ON H.invno = Q.invno
WHERE H.invno = @Invno 
  AND L.deleted = 0 
  AND M.deleted = 0 
  AND Q.deleted = 0
```

This code purpose is to show everything on my reporting service except the deleted one (filter it using a 'Deleted' column name instead of dropping some row(s).)

Now the problem is, if one of it doesn't have data, e.g: table M doesn't have anything, then the output will be blank.

Iv'e tried changing the logic to OR, but you know, the output will be funny (the 'Deleted = 1' will shown in the output and I don't want that.

Comment: You probably want a `LEFT JOIN` although you've got a bigger problem in that your `FROM` clause is pretty useless.

Comment: you are missing some tables from the select, please provide complete information about the data and table structure.

Comment: @tukan included, sorry for earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use outer joins and move the `deleted`checks to the join conditions (optional in case of the main table).

```
SELECT *
FROM Head H
LEFT JOIN Line L ON H.invno = L.invno
  AND L.deleted = 0 
LEFT JOIN Misc M ON H.invno = M.invno
  AND M.deleted = 0 
LEFT JOIN QSMU Q ON H.invno = Q.invno
  AND Q.deleted = 0
WHERE H.invno = @Invno
```

---

## INNER vs OUTER

`Head INNER JOIN Line ...` only takes the `Head` rows that have matching `Line` rows in the second table, i.e. show the orders that have at least 1 line item.

`Head LEFT JOIN Line ...` takes all the `Head` rows and appends `Line` rows (if available; NULLs otherwise), i.e. show all the orders, also the ones with no line items.

Comment: It works, thank you so much :) Can you elaborate why do we need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know the structure of the tables but from your `select` I see you have `inner join`.

You should understand what that really means - what you are doing is an intersection of `H` and `M` (see [Venn diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join) for more).

You should have done `LEFT JOINS` which shows you all results from `H` even when missing from `L` or `M` or `Q` (still keeping your select structure):

```
SELECT *
FROM Head H
LEFT JOIN Line L ON H.invno = L.invno
LEFT JOIN Misc M ON H.invno = M.invno
LEFT JOIN QSMU Q ON H.invno = Q.invno
WHERE H.invno = @Invno 
  AND L.deleted = 0 
  AND M.deleted = 0 
  AND Q.deleted = 0
```

Comment: Even with outer joins, the where clause may still filter out the rows, e.g. if there is no data in `Misc`, `M.deleted` will be NULL.

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz: true.  From the question I understood that she wants all that are in `Head` but not in the other tables `and` the additional conditions in the `where` clause.

Comment: My understanding was: _take all the rows from every table, except for the ones flagged as deleted_.

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz: which was correct as she accepted your answer.